# Change jQuery Slide size with Window Size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I need this slider to change to 1180x454 when the browser size is larger than 1280px. Not sure how to do @media type changes outside of CSS. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.noConflict();
    jQuery('#banner-example-1').paradigm(
                    {                                       
                        width:940,
                        height:362      

                });                     
        });

        </script>
```

Comment: What is preventing you from using CSS media queries?  Your example doesn't indicate why you need to change the size using javascript.

Comment: This didn't work as an override of the jQuery.                     @media screen 
and (min-width : 1281px) {
  #banner-example-1 {width: 1180px !important; height: 454px !important;}
}

Comment: You can check it here: http://www.sirkproductions.com/

Comment: Ahhh, so you're saying that you initially set the width and height using javascript, but once you do that, that essentially locks it to that height and width.  Is that right?

Comment: There's no documentation that I can find on that slider, so bear with me. Is it possible for you to remove the width and height from paradigm init method there and just apply a class to the #banner-example-1 that sets the height and width?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. The width and height set in jQuery add inline style for height and width to multiple elements of the slider.

Comment: The !important in the media query won't override the inline style set by the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution, but given some of the limitations of the slider, it seems like you may have no alternative than to roll your own scaling functionality as the window resizes.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // put your code here to trigger resizing of your slider
});
```

[Here's a basic jsfiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/pvanhouten/GxULV/1/).  You could do something like this where you check to see if the window size is a certain width and if so, include javascript to do the resizing of the paradigm divs that have inline widths and heights set.

EDIT: Updated jsfiddle to include logic for changing width on the element.  Unfortunately I can't tell you specifics on what you need to do to trigger that size change for paradigm since the documentation isn't public, so you might need to contact the developer for assistance with that if it isn't something simple like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // If > 1280 then width: 1180, height: 454 else width: 940, height: 362
  var width, height;
  if (this.outerWidth > 1280) {
    width = "1180px";
    height = "454px";
  }
  else {
    width = "940px";
    height = "362px";
  }
  $("#banner-example-1").css("width", width);
  $("#banner-example-1").css("height", height);
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not really sure how to utilize this. I'm an amateur with javascript. I assume I need an if else statement. If > 1280 then width: 1180, height: 454 else width: 940, height: 362. I'm not sure how to wrap it with this function though.

Comment: You'll probably also want to add something to page load to set the initial height / width by either pulling that logic I showed into a function of its own or by adding that condition to your initial width / height setting.

Comment: Not working for me. I'm gonna contact the plugin developers. The only thing that seems to work is to load it twice in an if else statement within the window resize function, but it doesn't work really well. Loads properly but if you adjust the window size it goes crazy. Thanks a lot for your help.